# wxMaxima: textbook print possible at input?

Tags: maxima, wxmaxima

Using wxMaxima, is it possible with input cells to use natural print directly (sometimes also known as mathprint, textbook print, natural print, etc.)?

So, for example, instead of seeing linear text such as `(77+2.23)/2` like one would normally if programming, one would see it as one would use LaTeX, a blackboard, Mathematica, or a physical calculator supporting such notation.

That is to say, one would see for example something like the following:

```
77 + 2.23
---------
    2
```

I checked the settings window, but found no option for it. Maybe it is hidden somewhere, or maybe there is a non-standard way to do it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: OP, do you mean to say that the input cell should be displayed the same as the output cell? I.e., both input and output should be displayed with math formatting.

Comment: @RobertDodier: thank you for your question. Yes, I do mean math formatting, the same way you would see it in a math textbook or the same way standard math is written on a blackboard, etc. If I knew some sort of math formatting was supported on this site, I would have made it even clearer in the original post.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I don't know whether that's possible; if you don't get an answer here, try the issue tracker for the wxMaxima project. See: https://github.com/wxMaxima-developers/wxmaxima/issues/ As a work around, consider creating a noun expression, and then `ev(%, nouns)` to evaluate the nouns. E.g. `'integrate(<some expression>, x, minf, inf)` to see the integral displayed, and then `ev(%, nouns)` or just `%, nouns` at the input prompt.